# MVC3 Contrib not working in razor pages, but is fine in controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I've got MVC3Contrib installed.. strange thing is, the examples show that I could use them to render links in razor pages, something like this:

```
@( Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Index(), "Go home") )
```

This somehow never works for me.. Although, in my controllers, I can do

```
return new RedirectToRoute<MyController>(c => c.Index());
```

just fine.. The error I get is `The non generic link ActionLink cannot be used with type arguments`

It is as if the contrib isn't installed.. Infact, I don't even see the mvc future action link option in the intellisense

[image]

I just can't figure out why it is behaving so, Do I need to do anything extra here?

If you need any other info, please ask, I don't know what else I should be giving out here..

---

**EDIT**
Oh btw, I'm using MVC Areas, if that matters, I have about 3 areas and then the main controllers etc..

Comment: Are you including the MvcContrib namespaces in the views? @using MvcContrib[.namespace]?

Comment: @danludwig, no, I wasn't doing it (only because the tutorial I followed didn't) but from Darin's answer below I found out I had to include it in webconfig files.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace is in scope which is where thos extension methods are defined:

[image]

or add it to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file in order to bring this namespace in all views:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I suppose that in your controller code you have added `using MvcContrib.ActionResults;` which is why you are able to see the `RedirectToRouteResult<T>` class available.

Comment: Hi Darin, that did work! and yes, every time in my controller I refer to any contrib actions, I get the red wavy underline thing in and I hit ctrl+. to get the intellisense to add ``@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc`` .. and I thought that was how it worked.. is there any other way? adding it to view works.. so thanks so much!